# Confused Between sqlConnection and Dataset

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I'm new to databases and I'm wondering what's the difference betweeing using

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

over

```
DataSet DB = new DataSet("DB.xsd");
```

I've been fooling around with it and dragged a table from my database explorere into the designer for the dataset and it then reflected the data even after updates, but I'm not sure, for a back-end movie storage database what do I use.

Are datasets part of an sql connection and used to insert data?

Comment: What's the difference between orange and elephant? Well, almost everything between them is difference.

Comment: A `SqlConnection` is a connection to your database. The `DataSet` is an in-memory object that can hold data and it`s [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7se64052(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a string is used to give it  a name (so `DB.xsd` is not loaded if you think so). So both are entirely different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `SqlConnection` is a connection to your database. The `DataSet` is an in-memory object that can hold data and it's [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7se64052%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes a string is used to give it  a name (so `DB.xsd` is not loaded if you think so).

So both are entirely different things.

But you can load a `DataSet` from  a database with a `SqlConnection` and a `DataAdapter`:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName ORDER BY ColumnName", con))
{
    da.Fill(ds);
}
```

Now you can access the rows from the table, for example in a `foreach`:

```
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
```

Comment: Thank you i will add this to answer in 7 min. My one question is, on deployment how does my database get shipped out. And in order to write to data is it possible through SqlCommands using something like "INSERT INTO dbo.Movie (Name, Release Year, Producer) VALUES (" + title + ", " + Convert.ToInt32(yearReleased) + ", " + producer + ")"

Comment: @Snowfiring: Yes it's possible to insert records via `SqlCommand` and `INSERT INTO...`. But i assume that this is a different question and cannot be answered thoroughly in comments here. The same is true for deployment  and shipping.